# Rails: Page won't redirect after external API callback action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, callback

I've tried to debug this for 2 entire days now and I don't understand at all. I've tried redirect_to, render, respond_to, format.html, format.json, format.js. I've searched and tried numerous possible StackOverflow answers, and none have worked. I would really appreciate any help you can give.

Problem: Controller action does not redirect to root_url. The logs say that it has rendered the root_url but the page doesn't change.

Expected behavior: When a user clicks on the Generate New Recipe link, it submits a POST request and takes the user to the Recipe API modal. After the user has exited the modal, the Recipe API submits a callback to localhost:3000/callback/recipe_id?{{recipe_id}}. The Recipe#callback action then submits a GET request to the Recipe API. If the user has completed formulating their recipe, the Recipe API will return the completion time as JSON. The Recipe#callback action then updates the user, before redirecting them to the root_url.

Actual behavior: The Recipe API submits a callback, the Recipe#callback action successfully updates the user, but it does not redirect to root_url. Instead it stays on localhost:3000/recipe/new.

Apart from the defaults, the only gems used are: faraday, json and devise.

Errors: With format.js { ... }, it will throw `ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat)`.
But with format.html { ... }, it doesn't throw any errors. Instead it says: `Processing by PersonaController#callback as */*`

The only clue I could find is that in the browser, it says:

```
  "CAUTION: request is not finished yet!" (It stays like this forever)

  Headers: 
    Request URL: http://localhost:3000. 
    Request Method: GET. 
    Status Code: 200 OK. 
    Content-Type: text/html; 
    Accept: */*
```

.

```
class RecipeController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: :callback
  
  def new; end

  def create; end

  def callback                                                                     
    @user = current_user                                                           
    recipe_service = RecipeService.new
    recipe_result = recipe_service.retrieve_recipe_status(params[:recipe_id])         
    respond_to do |format|                                                         
      if @user.update(recipe_completed_at: recipe_result)                        
        format.js { render js: "window.location = #{root_path}" }         
        # The above will throw ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat) as an error.
        #also tried: format.html { redirect_to root_url }
        #also tried getting rid of respond_to and adding a regular redirect_to method.
      end                                                                          
    end                                                                            
  end                                                                              

  private
    def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:recipe_id)
    end
end
```

.

```
class RecipeService
  def retrieve_recipe_status(recipe_id)
    response = Faraday.get("https://...com/api/recipes/#{recipe_id}") do |request|
      request.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/json'
      request.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{Rails.application.credentials.recipe[:api]}"
    end
    if response.success?
      parsed_response_body = JSON.parse(response.body)
      recipe_status = parsed_response_body["data"]["attribute"]["status"]
      recipe_completed_at = parsed_response_body["data"]["attributes"]["complete-time"]
      recipe_status == "complete" ? recipe_completed_at.to_datetime : recipe:status
    else
      response.status
    end
  end
end
```

.

```
recipe/create.js.erb
const client = new Recipe.Client({
  apiId: '...',
  onLoad: (_error) => client.open(),
  onComplete: recipeId => {                                        
    fetch(`/recipe/callback?recipe_id=${recipeId}`);
  }   
});
```

.

```
/recipe/new.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Generate New Recipe', recipe_path, method: :post, remote: true %>
```

.

```
/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get 'recipe/callback'
  get 'recipe/new'
  post 'recipe', to: 'recipe#create'

  root 'posts#index'
  resources :posts
end
```

Comment: remove respond_to block completely and just write render :js and create callback js erb file and add window.location = '(add path here)' . try this might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that didn't work. Any other suggestions?